# Could not block IP address of brute force attack using modsecurity & core rule set

Tags: apache, window, mod-security2

We are using apache windows web server. When client hits our web URL we have a log in page (this is apache managed) that authenticates the user.
We need to take action for unsuccessful log in attempts by the user.
We wanted to delay log in process for the brute force attacker after 3 unsuccessful log in attempts.

For this we are experimenting the use of **Mod Security** module (**ModSecurity 2.x**) .

I have used the following configuration file in main apache config file (**httpd.conf**)

**modsecurity-minimal.conf**

**crs-setup.conf**

**REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf**

I have enabled the log and checked configuration statements are being executed. Logging is happening.
However even after 3 unsuccessful attempts the log in page is not delayed.
I have below settings in modsecurity-minimal.conf

```
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "403" "phase:4,id:4001,setvar:ip.block_script=+1,expirevar:ip.block_script=1800,msg:'Attack Detected'"
SecRule ip:block_script "@ge 2" "phase:1, deny, status:406, id:4002, msg:'Repetitive Attack from the same IP Address'"
```

Let me know ,how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an operator (probably @eq) here:

```
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "403" ...
```

Comment: I do not think that's the problem. The default operator is @rx and that would produce a match.

I suggest you try and display the value of the variable and check whether it is being augmented or not.